# How to add dynamic filters in arangodb

Tags: arangodb, aql

i want to handle dynamic query string in Arangodb

```
let condition = 'FILTER u.username == '+value

if(usingPhoneNumber){
   condition = 'FILTER u.phoneNumber == '+value
}

const query = aql`
   FOR u in users
      ${condition}
   RETURN u
`
```

if I do like this, I'm getting error like

ArangoError: AQL: syntax error, unexpected bind parameter near '@value0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can pass aql query into another aql query

```
let condition = aql`FILTER u.username == ${value}`

if(usingPhoneNumber){
   condition = aql`FILTER u.phoneNumber == ${value}`
}

const query = aql`
   FOR u in users
      ${condition}
   RETURN u
`
```

this fixes my issue. thank guys for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I guess your username and phone number are strings, so they must be between quotes.

```
let condition = 'FILTER u.username == "' + value + '"'

if(usingPhoneNumber){
   condition = 'FILTER u.phoneNumber == "' + value '"'
}

const query = aql`
   FOR u in users
      ${condition}
   RETURN u
`
```

Comment: the issue is not with 'value'. if we add any query(filter condition) using a variable like above then AQL is treating that as a string. And throwing bind variable error

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like

```
let condition = 'FILTER u.username == ${value}'

if(usingPhoneNumber){
   condition = 'FILTER u.phoneNumber == ${value}'
}
```

Assuming the value is getting something assigned, I feel this might work. Do let me know the error that comes up, in case it comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try adding the condition in the query.

```
 FOR u in users
      FILTER u.username ==${value0} OR  u.phoneNumber == ${value0}
 RETURN u
```

If this works for you, I supose the problem is the aql formater assumes all inserted values with ${} are bind parameters, wich will be iterated over and not a constant query declaration.

Your current script resolves to:

```
{ 
  "query" : "FOR u IN users @value0 RETURN c._key", 
  "bindVars" : { 
    "value0" : "'FILTER u.username == '+value" 
  }
```